# QtDesigner plugins with python (libpythonplugin not a valid Qt Plugin)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I am trying to build a Qt Designer (4.7.4, Mac OS X 10.6) plugin using pyQt. I have followed several instructions on-line like:

- http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Using_Python_Custom_Widgets_in_Qt_Designer
- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-pyqtdesigner.html

without success: the plugins do not appear in the list. When I go into the "About Plugins" box, I can see:

> The file
>   '/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/designer/libpythonplugin.dylib' is
>   not a valid Qt Plugin.

So I think that the plugin that makes Qt Designer awaver of pyqt plugins is not working. Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Please post if you find an answer. I am having the same problem.

Comment: @JakeRunzer: I was not able to find solution for this.